# How to allow public access on existing objects and newly uploaded objects in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Laravel and it's built-in library to upload my images to AWS S3, but upon uploading I'm getting "Access Denied" when trying to display images on my homepage.

I googled for these solutions and followed them, my bucket has "Block Public Access" turned off in hopes to allow public access to my existing and newly uploaded images.

My expected output is so show the images on my webpage wether they're an existing image or newly uploaded image.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/) is something you have already tried, but, worth a shout from the documentation.

**Update the object's ACL using the AWS CLI**

For an object that's already stored on Amazon S3, you can run this command to update its ACL for public read access:

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket awsexamplebucket --key exampleobject --acl public-read
```

Or, you can run this command to grant full control of the object to the AWS account owner, and read access to everyone else:

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket awsexamplebucket --key exampleobject --grant-full-control emailaddress=accountowneremail@emaildomain.com --grant-read uri=http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers
```